# How to automatically extract cited documents from pdf to .bib

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, arxiv

I'm writing a paper and most my citation are from arxiv. Those papers have many useful citations I want to re-cite. However to do that I have to extract many citations from pdf, find their canonical name and .bib entry, and finally, cite them.

What I want to achieve is take pdf (mostly from arxiv), and automatically generate .bib file with all cited papers inside.

Any tools or help is appreciated.

Comment: Interesting question. There is http://text2bib.economics.utoronto.ca/ which I believe works fairly well on text, so you would have to convert the PDF first. I would, however, advise you to find the references yourself instead of copying them from a paper directly - at least if you want to cite them yourself. That way you make sure that you don't copy errors and typos.

Comment: I have removed the `biblatex` tag, since the `biblatex` package and its styles are not directly related to your question. Initially I was dubious about the BibTeX tag as well, but given its broad tag description about `.bib` files I left it.

Comment: Use NASA ADS.  Just a random example: for this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.00684 visit http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/bib_query?arXiv:1704.00684, follow the "References in the Article" and you'll get the list of all papers cited there, then in each page you can get a BibTeX entry by clicking on the "Bibtex entry for this abstract" link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System: http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abstract_service.html.  It indexes several scientific journals, mostly in the fields of astronomy/astrophysics, including all e-prints on arXiv.

For example, go to the page of this e-print: https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.00684, click on the "NASA ADS" button in the box on the right and you'll be directed to http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/bib_query?arXiv:1704.00684.  In this page, click on the "References in the Article" button and you'll get the list of all references cited in the paper.  Click on the [bibcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibcode) of one of them and in the abstract page you can click on the "Bibtex entry for this abstract" to automatically obtain the BibTeX entry for it.

At https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/ there is a fancier version of SAO/NASA ADS, with a more modern user interface.

Answer (score 11):

I've created a couple of bookmarklets to do this:

https://www.scholarcy.com/bookmarklets

They parse the PDF in the browser window and extract the citations as a .RIS or .bib file.

As such, it will work with any PDF, not just one on arXiv or that has a .tex source file

Alternatively, you can download the Scholarcy Chrome Extension which will also link each entry to the open-access version of the PDF for each cited paper (if there is one)

Full disclosure: I developed this tool and am the founder of Scholarcy.

Comment: To all the downvoters: How is this link-only answer worse than the other one?

Comment: When you are promoting your services, you [*have to disclose*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) your affiliation.  Otherwise this is considered spam.

Comment: Apologies, I thought the ‘I’ve created’ intro was sufficient. I’ve added disclosure at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scifinder (see if your university has an access for this).

1. You can search for the paper (in *scifinder*), whoose references you want to download.
2. After finding the paper, go to "**Get Related Citations**", and select "**Get Cited**".
3. You will get all the references that are cited in the paper.
4. Select all and **Export** these citations in .ris format, which can be opened in Mendeley/ Zotero.
5. These files can then be exported to .bib file.

I hope this helps :)
-AR